# config property not getting picked in micronaut

Tags: java, micronaut

I have tried to create the environment specific configuration in micronaut

with main **application.yml** as

```
micronaut:
    application:
        name: xyz
    server:
        port: 9090
    environments: local
```

and local configuration file as 
with name as **application-local.yml**

```
xyz:
  aws:
    accessKey: <access_key>
    secretKey: <secret_key>
```

In code I am trying to access as

```
@Value("${xyz.aws.accessKey}")
```

I while trying to access them in code getting following error

```
Message: Error resolving field value [${xyz.aws.accessKey}]. Property doesn't exist or cannot be converted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that there is no such properties in micronaut similar to spring's

```
spring.profiles.active
```

here instead we have to pass the external file as VM options instead

```
-Dmicronaut.environments=local
```

then it started to work

Comment: FYI, another option is you can set the `MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS` OS environment variable.  Both the `micronaut.environments` system property and the `MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS` OS environment variable accept a comma separated list as a value so multiple environments may be active concurrently.